# Get caption text without hidden span tag text

Tags: jquery, html

Here is a sample table :

```
<table id="table">
<caption>
  My Table <span style="display:none"> Hidden </span>
</caption>
<tr>
    <th>abc</th>
    <th>xyz</th>
</tr>
</table>


$(function(){ 
 CaptionText = $('#table').find('caption').text();
 alert(CaptionText);
});
```

How to avoid the hidden span tag text..
fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/y39e483q/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` method will return the text content of all the descendant elements also.

One solution is to do a manual filter to leave out the hidden element

```js
$(function() {
  var myTable = $('#table');
  var myCaptionText = myTable.find('caption').contents().filter(function() {
    return !$(this).is(':hidden')
  }).text();
  snippet.log('caption: ' + myCaptionText);
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <caption>
    My Table <span style="display:none"> Hidden </span>
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <th>abc</th>
    <th>xyz</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple use `clone` , and then `remove the span` and get the `text`

```
$('#table').find('caption').clone().remove('span').text().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery code 
  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y39e483q/6/)

```
  ($('#table caption').text()).replace($('span').text(),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(function(){ 
 myTable = $('#table');
 myCaptionText = myTable.find('caption').html();
 var substr = myCaptionText.split('<span');
 alert(substr[0]);
});
```

This will ignore the span tag inside the caption. You could simplify it like this.

```
$(function(){ 
     myTable = $('#table');
     myCaptionText = myTable.find('caption').html().split('<span');
     alert(myCaptionText[0]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like below

```
$(function(){ 
     myTable = $('#table');
     myCaptionText = myTable.find('caption').html().split('<span');
     alert(myCaptionText[0]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would have done:

```
$(function() {
  myTable = $('#table');
  myCaptionText = myTable.find("caption").text().replace($("table caption").find(":not(:visible)").text(), "")
  alert(myCaptionText);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qccLp2nr/)

Basically the code finds the hidden element within `<caption>` and replaces its text by blank in the final text.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try the answer below :** 

https://jsfiddle.net/myeo3a4r/2/
```

............................................

HTML

```
     <table id="containerDiv">
  <caption>You know, <span style="display:none"> I am inv<p>incible!</span>   </caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>January</td>
       <td>$100</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var _string = '';
   _childrenElements = document.getElementById('containerDiv').children;

  for(var i = 0; i < _childrenElements.length; i++) {
  if(_childrenElements[i].tagName == 'CAPTION') {
    _string = _string.concat(_childrenElements[i].textContent)  ;
    }
  }

  alert(_string);
```